# Migrate old question on CS education?

Tags: discussion, migration

In 2012, a [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/c-strings-vs-character-arrays) asked why is it that some professors teach C-style character arrays instead of C++ strings even in C++ classes.

Now that [Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com) is online, is it time to migrate this interesting question there, where it belongs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an [artificial restriction that prevents migrating questions that are more than 60 days old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).

In any case, we wouldn't migrate an *on-topic* question. Questions about computer science education are firmly on-topic on this site, regardless of what other Stack Exchange sites exist. The question in question is borderline, since it's about programming education, not computer science education. However, we tend to be more accepting of programming education questions here than programming questions, because programming is largely taught by computer scientists.